# How can I create a hyperlink in the middle of cell text using a formula?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Is there any way to *programmatically* concatenate text (e.g. using formulas) that includes hyperlinked text?

I am looking for a way to automate creation of documents that have links within long text descriptions in cells, e.g. invoices.

---

In Google Sheets, the
`HYPERLINK` function in Google Sheets returns hyperlink enabled text and the
`CONCATENATE` function allows stringing together or appending various texts.

| Formula | Result |
| --- | --- |
| `=HYPERLINK("https://stackoverflow.com", "Stack Overflow")` | [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com) |
| `=CONCATENATE("SO: ", "https://", "stackoverflow.com")` | `SO: https://stackoverflow.com` *(hyperlink not enabled)* |

When `HYPERLINK` is used within `CONCATENATE`, however, **the hyperlinked text shows up as plain text.**

| Formula | Result |
| --- | --- |
| `=CONCATENATE("SO: ", hyperlink("https://stackoverflow.com", "Stack Overflow"))` | SO: Stack Overflow |

Use of CONCATENATE as arg in HYPERLINK works as expected.

| Formula | Result |
| --- | --- |
| `=HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE("https://", "stackoverflow.com"), "Stack Overflow")` | [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com) |

Comment: This is not the same question as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8970391/how-can-i-create-a-hyperlink-in-the-middle-of-cell-text [How can I create a hyperlink in the middle of cell text?]. The OP in that question did not specify the need for a programmatic or fomula-based solution. The working answers also do not provide a programmatic or formula-based solution.

Comment: Add google-apps-script tag since you're looking for programmatic answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can set multiple hyperlinks (as many as you wish) with this script (not by formula)

```
function multipleHyperLinks() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A1').setRichTextValue(SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue()
    .setText("go to ... stackoverflow")
    .setLinkUrl(10, 23, "https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=google%20sheets")
  .build());
};
```

[RichTextValueBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/rich-text-value-builder)

[setLinkUrl(startOffset, endOffset, linkUrl)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/rich-text-value-builder#setlinkurlstartoffset,-endoffset,-linkurl)

[image]

By the way, if you want to retrieve all the links, use

```
function getMultipleLinks() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  var rng = sh.getRange('A1')
  var richTexts = rng.getRichTextValue().getRuns()
  richTexts.forEach(function(richText){
    Logger.log('|'+richText.getText() + '| = ' + richText.getLinkUrl())
  })
}
```

## edit

Here is an automatic solution based on onEdit(e) function :

Type in a cell : `foo <link1|text1> foo <link2|text2> foo`

for instance : `go to ... <https://stackoverflow.com/|stackoverflow>`

add 'Edit:' at the beginning to reverse

```
// mike.steelson
// example
// go to <https://stackoverflow.com/|stackoverflow> and <https://www.amazon.fr/|amazon> here
// add Edit: at the beginning to reverse
function onEdit(event){
  var sh = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var rng = event.source.getActiveRange();
  var value = rng.getValue()

  if (value.substring(0,5).toLowerCase()=='edit:'){
    var richTexts = rng.getRichTextValue().getRuns()
    var txt=''
    richTexts.forEach(function(richText){
      if (richText.getLinkUrl()==null){
        txt+=richText.getText()
      }else{
        txt+= '<' +  richText.getLinkUrl() + '|' + richText.getText() + '>'
      }
    })
    rng.setValue(txt)
  } else {
    var occ1 = ExtractAllRegex(value,'<([^>]+)>',0)
    var occ2 = ExtractAllRegex(value,'>([^<]+)<',0)
    occ2.push('')
    if (sh.getName()=='mySheet' && occ1.length>0){
      var richText = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue()

      var txt = value.split('<')[0]
      for (var i=0; i<occ1.length; i++){
        var arr = occ1[i].replace('<','').replace('>','').split('|')
        txt += arr[1]
        txt += occ2[i].replace('<','').replace('>','')
      }
      txt += value.split('>')[value.split('>').length-1]
      richText.setText(txt)

      var start = value.split('<')[0].length
      for (var i=0; i<occ1.length; i++){
        var arr = occ1[i].replace('<','').replace('>','').split('|')
        var len = arr[1].length
        richText.setLinkUrl(start,start+len,arr[0])
        start += len + occ2[i].replace('<','').replace('>','').length
      }

      rng.setRichTextValue(richText.build())

    }
  }
}
function ExtractAllRegex(input, pattern,groupId) {
  return Array.from(input.matchAll(new RegExp(pattern,'g')), x=>x[groupId]);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to test this or implement it. Can you suggest a starting point or provide steps for how to get it into a sheet (or any accessible location) and how to call it from a cell?

Comment: ok, I will do that soon.

Comment: unfortunately we cannot edit partial text by custom formula https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49287090/apply-multiple-font-colors-to-the-text-in-a-single-google-sheets- cell I will work on another friendly solution

Comment: I have edited my proposal

Comment: @MikeSteelson, the first section for this is what I've been looking for! I was wondering if there was an alternative way to hyperlink between sheets and their cell range. Example: `.setText("go to ... Sheet2")
    .setLinkUrl(10, 23, **sheet2.getRange('A1') **")
  .build());`...     The edited code returns a link however would only like the code to go the sheet and not open a new tab. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

if this is your goal:

[image]

then this is possible to achieve only manually editing the cell (or with script). usage of any internal formula you think of will render it as "plain text" (eg. removing the hyperlink)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, not in that way. Hyperlink (via formula) will always include the whole text in the cell, but I recommend you, if possible, to arrange the whole text in the invoice to leave the hyperlink in a cell, with all the paragraphs around.

it's an idea of how I would try it.